# Python-Finding the amount of neighbours given a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

**Problem statment**
On the number line there are N houses (There can be more houses in 1 number). Two houses are said to be neighbours if the distance between them is less than some give D. (the distance between 2 houses which have the same number is one )
Find the number of all neighbours.

Mathematicaly the problem boils down to this. Given a multiset N and a number D
Find the number of houses where the distance between them is less than D

```
def main():
    number_of_ppl,distance=map(int, input().split())
    inputs=map(int,input().split())

    numbers=sorted(inputs)
    counter=0
    sum=0
    for x in range(0,len(numbers)):

        for y in range(i+1,len(numbers)):

                if abs(numbers[x]-numbers[y])<=distance:
                    counter +=1
                else:
                    break
        sum+=counter
        counter=0
    print(sum)

main()
```

This code works however it fails at 3 of the 8 test cases due to ineficient time. Is there something I am missing ?
How could I make this algorithem faster?
I tried using dictionaries but got the same result

P.S If it helps I can post the test cases where this program fails

Comment: what is the `number_of_ppl` for?

Comment: What is `i` in the `for y...`? Did you mean `x`?

Comment: It looks like you're checking both `abs(numbers[x]-numbers[y])` and `abs(numbers[y]-numbers[x])`, which should be the same thing. You could change the inner loop to something like `for y in range(x+1,len(numbers)):` to reduce how much the inner loop needs to check. I don't see where `i` is defined though, so I don't know what it's purpose is.

Comment: @westlife can you provide some cases (preferably the ones failing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is incomplete, but it seems you are doing 2 loops which if the distance is big enough, takes O(n^2) to run. This can be reduced to O(n log n). Note that when you iterate the numbers in order, when you analize the neighbours of arr[i], when looking at the neighbours of arr[i + 1] they will be the same + maybe some more.

```
    def main():
        number_of_ppl,distance=map(int, input().split())
        inputs=map(int,input().split())
        numbers = sorted(inputs)

        sum = 0
        pointer = 0
        for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
            while pointer < len(numbers) and number + distance >= numbers[pointer]:
                pointer += 1
            sum += (pointer - idx)
        print(sum)

    main()
```